# If $H$ acts freely and properly on $G$, then $H$ also acts freely and properly on any subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

I want to show that $O(n)$ acts freely and properly on $U(n)$ and am trying to use the following.

> If $H$ acts freely and properly on $G$, then $H$ also acts freely and properly on any subgroup of $G$.

My argument seems to show that this is true, but this feels like too strong of a statement to be true.

If $H\times X\rightarrow X$ is free, then $hx=x$ implies that $h$ is the idenity element. So clearly for any subset $X'$ of $X$ the action $H\times X'\rightarrow X'$ is also free.

Also if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a proper map, and $B$ any subset of $Y$, then the restriction $f:f^{-1}(B)\rightarrow B$ is also a proper map.

Comment: Why would a subgroup of $G$ be stable under the action of $H$?

Comment: @CaptainLama I realize this is not true now. Unless there is a simple extra condtion we could put on the subgroup of $G$, i think it might be best for me to simple delete this question

Comment: You just need to assume the subgroup is fixed by $H$